# Running part of script whilst other part is running -python

Tags: python

How am I able to run my line of code in the background whilst other part is running.I only want to run it from IDLE without the CLI. I want it something like this. Thanks in advance.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('The Music which i want run in the background')

#The code i want to run in the foreground
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library to achieve this.

```
from playsound import playsound
from multiprocessing import Process


process_for_sound = Process(target=playsound, args=('The Music which i want run in the background',))
process_for_sound.start()
process_for_sound.join()

#The code you want to run in the concurrently.
```

Comment: That is really helpful. How could I do it if I wanted to run something in the background other than playing music.

Comment: You can call any function of your choice by using this method. Please refer to the docs for much more advanced features.

Comment: I have tried your solution but only goes to concurrent code.

Comment: This is the solution that I've used for a similar problem of mine. If you could give a better explanation of what is required, I might be able to help you

Comment: I am making a game with turtle graphics and want the music to play in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=playsound, args=('\dir\to\music')).start()

'Concurrent code'
_________________
```

or you can simply:

```
playsound('\dir\to\music', 0)
```